# Cannot locate Apex Type for ID

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Here is my code coverage. In the UAT environment, I don't get any error, but when I validate in production, I have an error.

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=false)
public class LCC_App_rej_Return_shipment_cApexTest {
    @isTest
    public static void submitFinalApprovalTest(){
        //Id record=Schema.SObjectType.Sample_Request_Line__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Glove').RecordTypeId;
        Id recordId ='a0a0k000003hP8mAAE';
        sObject newObject2 = recordId.getSObjectType().newSObject();
        Test.startTest();
        LCC_App_rej_Return_shipment_cApex.submitFinalApproval(recordId);
        Test.stopTest(); 
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void submitFinalApprovalNoTest(){
        //Id record=Schema.SObjectType.Sample_Request_Line__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Glove').RecordTypeId;
        Id recordId ='a0a0k000003hP8mAAE';
        sObject newObject2 = recordId.getSObjectType().newSObject();
        Test.startTest();
        LCC_App_rej_Return_shipment_cApex.submitFinalApprovalNo(recordId);
        Test.stopTest(); 
        
    }
}
```

Here is the error,

```
    System.SObjectException: Cannot locate Apex Type for ID: a0a0k000003hP8mAAE
Stack Trace: Class.LCC_App_rej_Return_shipment_cApexTest.submitFinalApprovalTest: line 7, column 1
```

Kindly assist me on how to solve this error. Note that both methods have the same error. I believe it is because of id. Maybe I cannot put any id here. Because maybe one day people will delete that Id. But I not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the answer in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/getsobjecttype-on-casecomment-00a/29771 help

Comment: This code basically doesn't do anything - the hard-coded Id does not exist in test context, so your method call _would_ fail if it got there, but the call to `newSobject()` is never used. While it sounds like you may have hit undefined platform behavior, your code needs to be revised anyway for other reasons.

Comment: Please use the Contact Us link at the bottom of this page to have your [accounts merged](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/93905/atiqah?tab=profile).